# Count number of squares from a set of vertices, C++

Tags: c++, geometry

I have a **C++ code** for counting how many squares can be formed from a given set of points with X, Y coordinates. Sample input for 5 points looks like:

```
5
0 0
0 2
1 0
2 0
2 2
```

One important note is that squares are not required to be axis-aligned. Here is a working code, taken from 'codechef.com':

```
int N = 5;
std::vector<int> arr_x{0, 0, 1, 2, 2};
std::vector<int> arr_y{0, 2, 0, 0, 2};

int flag1 = 0;
int flag2 = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
        flag1 = 0;
        flag2 = 0;
        int x1 = arr_x[i], y1 = arr_y[i];
        int x2 = arr_x[j], y2 = arr_y[j];

        int p1_x = x1 - y1 + x2 + y2;
        int p2_x = x1 + y1 + x2 - y2;
        int p1_y = x1 + y1 - x2 + y2;
        int p2_y = -x1 + y1 + x2 + y2;

        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            if (2 * arr_x[k] == p1_x && 2 * arr_y[k] == p1_y) {
                flag1 = 1;
            }
            if (2 * arr_x[k] == p2_x && 2 * arr_y[k] == p2_y) {
                flag2 = 1;
            }
        }
        if (flag1 && flag2) count++;
    }
}
std::cout << count / 2 << std::endl;
```

I don't understand the logic and the meaning of `p1_x`, `p2_x`, `p1_y`, `p2_y`. If someone is able to give me explanation, please do it.

Comment: Given example contains 1 square, formed by 4 vertices : {0,0}, {0,2}, {2,0}, {2,2}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
```

iterates over all vertices. The second loop

```
    for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
```

iterates over all vertices after `i`. The algorithm assumes that the vertices are opposite corners and calculates the two missing vertices.

```
        int p1_x = x1 - y1 + x2 + y2;
        int p2_x = x1 + y1 + x2 - y2;
        int p1_y = x1 + y1 - x2 + y2;
        int p2_y = -x1 + y1 + x2 + y2;
```

The calculation is not quite correct to avoid floating point arithmetic. It should be e.g. `(x1 - y1 + x2 + y2) / 2`. Later the vertices are multiplied with `2` to correct this. In the last loop

```
        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
```

the two missing vertices are searched. A flag is set if a vertex is found.

```
            if (2 * arr_x[k] == p1_x && 2 * arr_y[k] == p1_y) {
                flag1 = 1;
            }
            if (2 * arr_x[k] == p2_x && 2 * arr_y[k] == p2_y) {
                flag2 = 1;
            }
        }
```

If both missing vertices are found this square is counted.

```
        if (flag1 && flag2) count++;
    }
}
```

Because each square is counted twice the number of squares is divided by two.

```
std::cout << count / 2 << std::endl;
```

Example for the calculation:

Vertex 1 is (0, 0). Vertex 2 is (2, 0). Then the both missing vertices are (1, 1) and (1, -1). Let's try the calculation:

```
p1_x = (0 - 0 + 2 + 0) / 2 = 1
p2_x = (0 + 0 + 2 - 0) / 2 = 1
p1_y = (0 + 0 - 2 + 0) / 2 = -1
p2_y = (0 + 0 + 2 + 0) / 2 = 1
```

The result is the two missing vertices.